# How do I access the User Database of my website... Asp.net mvc EF 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this code on my AccountModel. Visual Studio created it for me.

```
 public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller I have this:

```
 public class UsuarioUxController : Controller
{

    private KekantoContext db = new KekantoContext();
    private UsersContext userDb = new UsersContext();

 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(userDb.UserProfiles);
    }
```

I am trying to access the User database but I am being unsuccessful....The count for `userDb.UserProfiles` is giving me `count=0`, and I already have users in my database.

Comment: did you try to debug on `return View(userDb.UserProfiles)`? and see what is going on.

Comment: are you trying to connect to an 'existing db' ? if so it's likely out of sync - or even entirely different connection. Did you enable migrations, is it local or live site etc. more info...

Comment: I debugged return View(userDb.UserProfiles) ... and the count is returning 0....I want to connect to the database that holds the users of my website

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `DefaultConnection` connection string is pointing to the correct database in the configuration file, i.e

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="your connection string" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: My conectionString is fine... There are other data that I can access  successulfuly... But my user data I cant access